# NGRX: TypeError: Actions must have a type property

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Being new to `ngrx` I am facing an exception and not sure why...

I am trying to `dispatch` an `action` and handle it in an `effect`, but I keep getting the error: `TypeError: Actions must have a type property`

Actions:

```
export const TEST_ACTION = 'test_action';
export class TryTest implements Action {
    readonly type = TEST_ACTION;

    constructor(public playload: any) {
    }
}
export type MyActions = TryTest;
```

Effects:

```
import * as MyActions from "./myactions.actions";

@Injectable()
export class MyEffects {
    @Effect()
    testEffect = this.actions$
        .ofType(MyActions.TEST_ACTION)
        .map((action: MyActions.TryTest) => {
            return 'something'
        });

    constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}
}
```

Component:

```
this.store.dispatch(new MyActions.TryTest({ name: 'test' }));
```

I am using:

effects: 4.0.5 and store: 4.0.3

Comment: I think you need to add paranthesis (`()`) when you want to dispatch a new action, otherwise the constructor is not called: `this.store.dispatch(new MyActions.TryTest({ name: 'test' })());`

Comment: Thanks David for the time, but I think I invoking the constructor and passing the object {name:test}

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I misread your code! nevermind!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this helps someone else starting...Turns out I was not returning the Action that ngrx is expecting in the map operator.

Comment: same happened with me I was returning of(myaction) instead of myaction

Answer (score 5):

because effect must return an action at the end.
so you have two choices:

1. return a {type: string} object
2. return a new Action()

   ```
   import * as MyActions from "./myactions.actions";

   @Injectable()
   export class MyEffects {
       @Effect()
       testEffect = this.actions$
           .ofType(MyActions.TEST_ACTION)
           .map((action: MyActions.TryTest) => {
               return {type:'your_action'}
           });

       constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}
   }
   ```

Comment: Please do do not only post code. Instead add an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

by default all effects you create are supposed to emitt an action which is dispatched to the store. 
Thus, as result from effect function, you need to return type `Observable<Action>` where Action is an interface from @ngrx/store:

```
export interface Action {
    type: string;
}
```

So mapping to object with property `type` will work:

```
 @Effect() testEffect = this.actions$
             .ofType(MyActions.TEST_ACTION)
             .map((action: MyActions.TryTest) => {
                    return {type:'action_for_test_effect'}
              });
```

In this case, you should support `action_for_test_effect` in your reducer.

If you don't need to dispatch any action from effect, you can disable it by adding config object to effect:

```
@Effect({dispatch: false}) testEffect = this.actions$
                 .ofType(MyActions.TEST_ACTION);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have written wrong Action class, Query.action.ts file is having all the actions for the store, in here I have made a silly mistake.

in the line **readonly type = QueryActionTypes.SaveQuery;** instead of assiging the variable type, I have just defined it.

I have used colon **":"** instead of equal **"="**.

I have written **readonly type : QueryActionTypes.SaveQuery;**

```
export enum QueryActionTypes {
 SaveQuery = '[Query] Save Query'
}

export class SaveQuery implements Action {
   readonly type = QueryActionTypes.SaveQuery;
   constructor(public payload: { Query : Query}) {}
}

export type QueryActions = SaveQuery
```

So ngrx unable to find property **type** in **SaveQuery** class (because I have used colon : instead of equal =) which implements Action class. This Action class needs type property

Comment: Thanks and Good catch.  Tough one because the error is run time and you're tasking between javascript and json with NO compile errors.  Runtime error:   'ERROR TypeError: Actions must have a type property"   threw me because I see I defined it (Wrong) but I would think that would be a compile error.